# I want to play Media when i close the Interstitial advertisement. Not before

Tags: android, ads, media, banner, interstitial

I have a MediaPlayer and music.start(); is working correctly. Also i have an Interstitial advertisement and loading in onCreate. Advertisement is also working fine. I want to play music after closing the advertisement. For now; music is playing when i see the ad. I want to stop the music when i see the ad. and play again after closing add. How can i do that?

```
private AdRequest adRequest2;
private InterstitialAd minterstitialAd;
private MediaPlayer music;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level6);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   
    adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    
    InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-1245895864529409/518807", adRequest2, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
            System.out.println("Ad Loaded");
            minterstitialAd=interstitialAd;
            minterstitialAd.show(Level6.this);

        }
           @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                System.out.println("Ad Load Failed");
                minterstitialAd=null;
            }

        });
 

music=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.oyun);
music.start;}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following are all the available methods you can call on your interstitial ad in your case the onAdOpened is where you should stop the music and onAdClosed method is where you should play the music

```
@Override
public void onAdLoaded() {
    // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
}

@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
    // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
}

@Override
public void onAdOpened() {
    // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
}

@Override
public void onAdClicked() {
    // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
}

@Override
public void onAdLeftApplication() {
    // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
}

@Override
public void onAdClosed() {
    // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
}
```

so in your code add the onAdClosed method and play music in it

```
InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-1245895864529409/518807", adRequest2, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
        System.out.println("Ad Loaded");
        minterstitialAd=interstitialAd;
        minterstitialAd.show(Level6.this);

    }
       @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            System.out.println("Ad Load Failed");
            minterstitialAd=null;
        }
       @Override
       public void onAdClosed() {
          // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
          music=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.oyun);
           music.start;
        }

    });
```